# For a Plummer model mass distribution, what is the timescale of dissolution?

Tags: astronomy, astrophysics

Given an initial system of masses distributed in a [Plummer model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plummer_model) close encounters cause stars to gain enough energy to leave the system. What is the timescale over which the whole cluster with *N* particles evaporates?